# Handling Lambda Expressions with Interface java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Since I have an `interface` with two methods, how do I implement it with a concrete class? How do I write Lambda expressions for these two methods?

```
 interface LambdaExpression {
     void methodA();
     void methodB();
 }
```

Comment: Your interface is not a [functional interface](http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, please don't edit out proper grammar and/or punctuation. You've made this nearly unreadable.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Sorry, there was a race condition between the two edits, for some reason "the system" decided to take my (less elaborate) edit. I didn't even attempt to fix the grammar or add any punctuation in this one. Could one roll it back to your version somehow, I agree that your version made much more sense.

Comment: No worries @AndreyTyukin. I think you can roll yours back if you want.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils ok, rolled back to your version, additionaly changed "Experession" to "Expression". [cleaning up the comment section]

Answer (score 3):

You can not. Lambda expressions are for functional interfaces ie interface with only one abstract method.

Comment: What are solutions for this case in Java 8

Comment: @WaseemSaeed: create two interfaces with one abstract method each.

Comment: Thanks @Anurag That is the only solution I guess. Thanks, Mate.!